# Disk Usage is increasing rapidly, fixed after Server restart

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

It was suggested to me that this may be the case: Sometimes it happens that you still have a file handle open to a file that has been deleted.

df -ht   shows the disk usage increasing rapidly - like 1 GB per day.
du -skh  does not show any disk usage increase in areas that i control, except in weird parts like /proc (areas that should not be deleted)

A server restart will free up all the extra used disk usage.

How can I track down the process or file that is responsible for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can grep deleted open files from the output of lsof:

```
lsof | grep deleted
```